# Is the "of" necessary in "that of whether"?

Tags: prepositions

There is a question about ["that of which"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/that-of-which-you-vs-that-which-you) in which case the "of" is necessary.  I'm wondering if the "of" is necessary in "that of whether.

Here is an example:

> A prominent question in metaphilosophy is that of whether
>   philosophical progress occurs, and more so, whether such progress in
>   philosophy is even possible.

It seems to me that dropping the "of" does not change the meaning.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177089/using-of-before-whether-and-general-usage-of-whether) seems related.

Comment: It makes it ungrammatical.

Comment: @Jim Do you mean the "of" is grammatically necessary?

Comment: Yes.  Without it one is left waiting for a predicate after the word *possible*.

Comment: You can't drop "of" leaving just "that" remaining. The interrogative clause _whether philosophical progress occurs remains_ is introduced by the interrogative subordinator "whether". But "that" is also a subordinator, though not an interrogative one, so you'd end up with two subordinators introducing the clause, which makes no sense and would be ungrammatical. _A prominent question in metaphilosophy is whether philosophical progress occurs_ is fine and does not change the meaning

Comment: To explain about "that": In _A prominent question in metaphilosophy is that of whether philosophical progress occurs_, the item "that" is not a subordinator, but a pronoun used anaphorically to refer back to the noun phrase _a prominent question_, so we understand _A prominent question in metaphilosophy is the prominent question of whether philosophical progress occurs_. The pro-form "that" simply avoids the repetition of "a prominent question". But if you drop "of", then the clause structure changes and "that" becomes a subordinator rendering the clause ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the sentences in question:

1. (*original*) A prominent question in metaphilosophy is that of whether philosophical progress occurs, and more so, whether such progress in philosophy is even possible.
2. (*dropped 'of'*) A prominent question in metaphilosophy is that whether philosophical progress occurs, and more so, whether such progress in philosophy is even possible.

Here are a couple of major changes that dropping "*of*" introduces:

- The word *that* in #1 forms part of the phrase *that of*, which refers back to the opening phrase. It (*that*) may be replaced by the phrase *the prominent question* while retaining the meaning of the sentence. In #2, it acts as a [conjunction](http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/), introducing the following clause. *That* and *the prominent question* aren't 'drop-in replacements' for each other in #2.
- The phrase *whether philosophical progress occurs* is the immediate "prominent question" in #1. In #2, it is a dangling clause. Removing *of* to produce #2 causes the whole sentence to become incomplete. Instead of the question being "whether X is Y" as it is in both *whether* causes of #2, it needs to be a statement along the lines of *whether [condition], [conclusion]*, asserting that regardless of the truth of the *condition*, the *conclusion* holds.

You ask:

> Is the “of” necessary in “that of whether”?

Since you want to retain the meaning of the sentence you quoted, yes, it is necessary. However, if you remove "*that of*" instead of just "*of*", you retain the meaning of the original sentence, as noted by Janus Bahs Jacquet in comments to this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer!  I'm not getting the example of aposiopesis though

Comment: I’d say if you drop the _of_, you’ll have to introduce an ellipsis instead. “A question is that whether X is Y” is simply ungrammatical like that. “A question is that… whether X is Y” is grammatical as _spoken language_, where the sentence is stopped to be rephrased in the middle. If properly prepared and written down as a continuous, non-broken sentence, dropping _of_ would also entail dropping _that_: “A question is whether X is Y”.

Comment: @zjk It's a pleasure. In the example, the first sentence is left hanging without saying what they did (e.g. theft, but likely something much more horrible).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. I now think dropping *of* goes beyond aposiopesis - it breaks the grammar of the sentence completely. I agree that dropping the word *that* as well resolves the issue. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I like your answer except for the first sentence.

Comment: @Jim Thanks. What is it about the first sentence you don't like? I'm also a little dissatisfied with it - in particular, that *tone* doesn't cover quite enough. I chose to use it because some of the original intent, and certainly some of the subject matter, still comes through. My intent was to say something about the *essence* of what had changed between #1 and #2. I'm interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @Lawrence - You may drop the word ***of*** but then it becomes ungrammatical.  Your sentence seems to indicate that it’s okay but just means something different. (see your conversation with Janus above)

Comment: @Jim Fair enough. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Lawrence - Nice.  +1